# urls.py and redirecting urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'crm/',RedirectView.as_view(url='/crm/accounts/login'), name='home'),
    url(r'^crm/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

and accounts.urls has two records

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout, name='logout'),
)
```

But when I access localhost:8000/crm/ (with or without the trailing slash) it takes me to localhost:8000/crm/accounts/ and not accounts/login as it says in RedirectView. I was testing something with using /crm/accounts as a parameter to RedirectView.as_view but after changint it it won't work. Restarted server and browser.

Comment: i'm not sure that's the answer, but maybe the trailing ^ is important - as in url('^crm/'. ...)

Comment: Yes I added that and worked. Almost...It redirects me to the correct page but chrome gives a message like this pages contains a loop of redirect or something and won't open the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change order of following two lines. (also prepend `^` in front of `crm/`.)

```
url(r'^crm/',RedirectView.as_view(url='/crm/accounts/login'), name='home'),
url(r'^crm/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

Or, change `crm/` to `^crm/$` to make it only match `crm/`, not `/crm/accounts/...`.

```
url(r'^crm/$',RedirectView.as_view(url='/crm/accounts/login'), name='home'),
url(r'^crm/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

Othersie, access to `/crm/accounts/login` , `/crm/accounts/logout` is handled by `RedirectView.as_view(url='/crm/accounts/login')` because the first url pattern matched first is used.

Comment: And now chrome won't let me open page becuast there were to many redirects...How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: @Apostolos, Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Did you changed the url configuration as I suggested in the answer?

Comment: Yes it works fine, it redirects me to /crm/accounts/login/ but browsers(both chrome and firefox) give me a message about exceeding redirect limit(firefox) and large number of redirects(chrome). How can I solve this?

Comment: @Apostolos, What happend if you change `RedirectView.as_view(url='/crm/accounts/login')` with `RedirectView.as_view(url='/crm/accounts/login/')` (appending slash) ?

Comment: The same with or without leading slash...It's the first time it happens. I used to have it without the crm, and just added crm, I mean WTH...

Comment: @Apostolos, I meant a trailing slash in the last comment.

Comment: The same with or without the trailing slash...It says I have exceeded redirect limit...Oh I am on development server of django

Comment: It worked after some refresh(before changing the order of two urls) but I chose to change the order either ways. Why did this happen?Any clue?Will It happen on production?

Comment: Accessing `/crm/accounts/login` does not match the url pattern `/crm/accounts/login/`, but matches `/crm`  (without trailing slash)` => cause redirect => ....

Comment: Thnx for helping me. So is it bad  to have redirects on your page?

Comment: @Apostolos, No, I don't think it is bad. But you should carefully design url as you saw (especially when there's urls that share prefix).

Comment: So if users wanted to always use /crm as url and not crm/acounts/login/ by them selves it would cause exceeding redirect limit correct?